# What is the best way to create a web interface to an interactive perl script?

Tags: perl, cgi

I have a interactive perl shell script that asks the user for some input and accordingly with his choice the script returns another set of options to choose from.
Now, soon I will have a demand to create a web interface for it. No more black terminals with blinking prompt for our users.
I was wondering what is the best way to pull this off with minimum changes to the original script? How to keep the script running and wait for user input? What is the best way to send user input to the script and then return it?
Or should I refactor the script to use CGI? I want to hear some general direction that I should take. I already know just the basic of Perl and CGI.

Comment: You're pretty well going to have to go the CGI route in some fashion... otherwise you'll just have to create some intermediary translator which will certainly cause grief in the long term.

Comment: `Mojolicious::Lite` is perhaps a better place to look that CGI.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CGI these days you might as well be using something modern and fast like [Plack](http://www.plackperl.org). Since Plack will wrap a CGI style application you can even use a CGI application "inside" Plack to get modern features, pluggable middleware, etc., alongside olde-fashioned 1990's traditions.

Depending on how complex your application is there's a number of small frameworks and helper modules that can make working with Plack easier.  Converting a console application to use a web interface might be easier if you use something like [Squatting](https://metacpan.org/release/Squatting) or [Kelp](https://github.com/naturalist/kelp).